# How to modify csv and excel workbook and save back into the same files?

Tags: c#, excel, csv

So my program takes in 2 file types, .csv and .xlsx.
I have 2 methods that checks if the data inside the files are validated. If the files are validated, it just returns true

Else, in addition to returning false, I want to add a extra column call it 
"Errors" and I want write to specific error messages into the cells.

For example,

if the Data.csv originally looks likes this
First row are the column names A-G

A | B | C | D | E | F | G

Row 1

Row 2

Row 3

....

Assuming row and columns are 0 indexed

If a data type is wrong in Row 3 column B (cell[4][1]) and Row 2 column G (cell[2][6]), I want to create a column after G called H and in Row 2 column H and Row 3 Column H, I would have a message of what went wrong.

Like so

A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |

Row 1

Row 2                        B is of wrong type

Row 3                        G is of wrong type

......

Here are my methods

I'm using Excel Interlop for xlsx

```
   private bool FileValidatorXlsx()
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(_filename, ReadOnly: true);
        foreach (Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet in xlWorkbook.Worksheets)
        {
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                string row = "";
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                {
                    if (xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 == null)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // These 2 columns consist of time format (h:mm);                               
                        if (j == 6 || j == 7)
                        {
                            row += (xlRange.Cells[i, j].Text);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row += (string)xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
                        }

                        // Don't want to append , to the last item
                        if (j < colCount)
                        {
                            row += ',';
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if the record (row) is not valid, just return false
                if (!ValidateRecord(row))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

this one validates csv

```
    private bool FileValidatorCsv()
    {
        string currentLine;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_filename))
        {
            currentLine = sr.ReadLine();
            while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!ValidateRecord(currentLine))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

helper method that validates individual rows

```
private bool ValidateRecord(string record)
{
    List<string> row;
    switch (_fileType)
    {
        case ((int)extensionTypes.CSV):
            row = record.Split(',').ToList<string>();
            if (row.Count != 9)
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        case ((int)extensionTypes.XLSX):
            row = record.Split(',').ToList<string>();
            if (row.Count != 9)
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;

    }
    return IsValidRow(row);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should work inside your loop.

```
xlWorksheet.Cells[RowIndex: i, ColumnIndex: 7].Value = "My error message";
```

Comment: I tried the above, but however, I didn't see any changes made in the excel. Also I had to remove ReadOnly:true

Comment: mmm after a lot of playing around, I think I finally got it to work. I think the issue was within Excel process not properly closed or something. Thanks!